# Inoic build android faild: Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I have written an ionic app, and I want to run it on my mobile device by click run from Andriod studio and got error messages as below:

```
Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
.../CameraLauncher.java:40
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider
```

I guess it would caused by the Camera plugin I have used, just don't know which step I did incorrectly.

AndroidManifest.xml in android studio attached:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Comment: did you find a fix?

Comment: Yes, since I am using the capacitor, and I didn't use any of the Cordova plugins, after removing the unnecessary Cordova plugin used in package.json, the issue has been solved.